# Automatic Creation of Objects in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, object

I am trying to write a function that can create a large number of objects of a certain class using dynamic allocation.

Let's say I have a class `ExampleClass` and I can create one object `object1` with a name "A1" as follows:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class ExampleClass{
public:
    string name;
    ExampleClass(string aName){
        this->name = aName;
    }
};



int main() {
    ExampleClass* object1 = new ExampleClass("A1");
    cout<<"I am "<< object1->name <<"."<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How could I write a function that takes `N`, a number of objects desired, and automatically creates `N` objects of the class `ExampleClass`?

So the function should look something like:

```
void createObjects(int N){
    //Creating N objects of the class Example Class
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++){
        ExampleClass* a_new_object_for_each_i = new ExampleClass("a_new_name_for_each_i");
    }
}
```

If `N=1,000`, this function should be able to create something like objects: `object1,object2,...,object1000` with names "A1","A2",...,"A1000" respectively.

Please note that the names for objects and the string names can not be supplied as arguments to the function.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: Simply use a `std::vector<ExampleClass>` and return that from your function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you, but this does not solve the issue of automatically assigning names for objects and for string names.

Comment: @Kivis You can easily generate the name using string concatenations, what's your problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know how to work with strings, but not sure how to create whatever will be put into the place of object1 in my toy example. It is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply using a `std::vector<ExampleClass>` like this:

```
std::vector<ExampleClass> createObjects(int N){
    std::vector<ExampleClass> result;
    //Creating N objects of the class Example Class
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++){
        result.push_back(ExampleClass("A" + std::to_string(i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This works, however, it does not use the dynamic allocation as required with 'new'.

Comment: @Kivis _"however, it does not use the dynamic allocation as required with 'new'"_ It does, `std::vector` does that internally and you don't have to mess with it.